# Thymeleaf, fragments and default parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have created fragments.html file. It contains the following fragment:

```html
<div th:fragment="my_fragment(content)">
    <p th:text="${content}"></p>
</div>
```

I put the above fragment into my view file:

```html
<div th:replace="fragments :: my_fragment('test')"></div>
```

Now, I want to pass two parameters to my_fragment, but I must ensure backward compatibility.

I tried to solve the problem as follows:

```html
<div th:fragment="my_fragment(content, defaultParameter='default value')">
    <p th:text="${content}"></p>
</div>
```

Unfortunelly, the above solution generated error:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Cannot resolve
>   fragment. Signature "my_fragment (content,defaultParameter='default value')"
>   declares 2 parameters, but fragment selection specifies 1 parameters.
>   Fragment selection does not correctly match.

Any idea?

Answer (score 66):

Thymeleaf allows a signature of a fragment without explicit parameters like this:

```
<div th:fragment="my_fragment">
    <p th:text="${content}"></p>
    <p th:text="${defaultParameter}"></p>
</div>
```

To call this fragment and pass `content` and `defaultParameter` you may call the fragment as follows:

```
<!-- both parameters not specified -->
<div th:replace="fragments :: my_fragment"></div>
<!-- only content parameter specified -->
<div th:replace="fragments :: my_fragment(content='a')"></div>
<!-- both parameters specified -->
<div th:replace="fragments :: my_fragment(content='a', defaultParameter='b')"></div>
```

But the below will not work:

```
<div th:replace="fragments :: my_fragment('a', 'b')"></div>
```

And the message is self-explanatory:

```
 Signature "my_fragment" declares no parameters, but fragment selection did specify parameters in a synthetic manner (without names), which is not correct due to the fact parameters cannot be assigned names unless signature specifies these names.
```

So in case you want to maintain backward compatibility, you should use named parameters while calling a fragment and do not specify parameters in a signature of a fragment.

Comment: Is it possible to set default value for the `<p th:text="${defaultParameter}"></p>` so it doesn't come up empty if parameter is not entered?

Comment: @perak yes it is by using th:with inside the fragment declaration tag. I have an example provided in my answer.

Comment: What one mustn't forget when passing variables, rather than literals, is to wrap those in `${}` e.g. `<th:block th:replace="common::buttons(fooBar = ${bar})" />`

Comment: Is there any syntax to have it work with message resources?  I tried the below in several styles all failing.  <th:block th:replace="fragments/core00Frag::header(title='[[#{title.index}]]')"/>

Comment: try without quote, <th:block th:replace="fragments/core00Frag::header(title=#{title.index})"/>

Answer (score 44):

The best way to allow optional parameter for a fragment is to declare them with "th:with" and describe them with meaningful default values.

So, you define explicit your mandatory and your optional values in the declaration tag of your fragment.

Here is simple example, with 1 mandatory and 2 optional parameters:

```
<div th:fragment="printGreetings (name)" th:with="title=${title} ?: 'Mr.', greeting=${greeting} ?: 'Hello'">
    <span th:text="${greeting}">Hello</span>
    <span th:text="${title}">Mr.</span>
    <span th:text="${name}">John Doe</span>
</div>
```

You can then call it like the following:

```
<div th:replace="fragments :: printGreetings (name='daniel')">
   Hello Mr. Daniel
</div>
<div th:replace="fragments :: printGreetings (name='Lea', title='Ms.')>
   Hello Ms. Lea
</div>
<div th:replace="fragments :: printGreetings (name='Lea', title='Ms.', greeting='Hi')>
   Hi Ms. Lea
</div>
```

(Please note that all values inside the tags are replaced by the dynamic ones. It's just for better reading.)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to provide a default value (as in your case) you can use the elvis operator to specify a default value, for example:

```html
<div th:fragment="my_fragment">
    <p th:text="${content}"></p>
    <p th:text="${defaultParameter ?: 'the backwards compat value'}"></p>
</div>
```

see: [elvis-operator](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#default-expressions-elvis-operator)

Answer (score 2):

At last I've solved task like this:

```
<div th:fragment="my_fragment2(content, param2)">
    <th:block th:replace="my_fragment(${content})"/>
</div>

<div th:fragment="my_fragment(content)" th:with="param2=${param2} ?: 'default value'">
    <p th:text="${content}"></p>
    <p th:text="${param2}"></p>
</div>

<div th:replace="fragments :: my_fragment2('test', 'my_value')"></div>
```

But it is overhead:(

Also ask a question to issue [Allow fragment parameters to have default values](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/350)

Answer (score 1):

The best way for me :

Fragment:

```
<div th:fragment="my_fragment(content)">
    <p th:text="${content}"></p>
</div>
```

if content is given from model:

`<div th:replace="fragments :: my_fragment(${content})></div>`

else:

`<div th:replace="fragments :: my_fragment('content')></div>`