# Optional arguments in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

Is it possible to create a fragment in Thymeleaf taking optional arguments?

```
<div th:fragment="personfragment(name, age, optionalargs...)">
```

So I could call it with either:

```
<div th:replace="personfragment('john', '28', 'arg1')" />
<div th:replace="personfragment('john', '28', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3')" />
```

This is *not* a duplicate, as I don't know the number of args beforehand. That's what optional arguments are for: not having to set the number or arguments!

I'd also be happy if someone knows how to pass parameters just as an array-parameter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thymeleaf, fragments and default parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093149/thymeleaf-fragments-and-default-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Use a single parameter that is an object.

You can then inspect the object inside your fragment and extract the relevant properties if they exist.